# Can someone explain to me how the environ variable works in C++?

Tags: c++, getenv

I'm trying to write my own version of getenv. I haven't started yet so I'm trying to understand environ first.

If it's a global why can't I print it in my function? Is environ a String or an array of chars? Why is environ a double pointer? Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
void myenv(char*);

void myenv(char* name)
{
std::cout<<environ;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv, char** environ)
{
myenv("PATH");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`environ` is a `char**`. It points at an array of `char*`, each of which points to a string of `char`. So it's like an array of strings. For example, `environ[0]` is a null-terminated string. Try printing out that:

```
std::cout << environ[0];
```

Each string is an environment variable of the form `name=value`. They correspond to the environment variables for the current process.

However, `environ` is not a feature of C++ and is non-portable. It comes from the `unistd.h` header which is defined by POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

It's a `char **` containing the env. variables

`extern char **environ;`

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/environ.html

Answer (score 0):

Just adding;

> Is environ a String or an array of chars? Why is environ a double pointer?

environ addresses an array of pointers, that each point to the first address of a character string.  The environment isn't one string, it is a bunch of strings (well, the environment could be empty, so that "bunch" can be zero).

```
environ[0] contains a pointer to the 'first' environment variable.
environ[1] contains a pointer to the 'second'.

environ[0][0] would reference the first character of the 'first' name in the environment.
environ[1][0] would reference the first character of the 'second' name.
```

*Or if there isn't at least two environment variables, environ[1] points off into segfault land or worse, random memory*.

I quoted first and second, as there are no defined rules as to how environment name strings are ordered, (don't expect the names to be alphabetical order for instance).